# How can I check if one value is A or B and another value is A or B?

Tags: java, if-statement, logical-operators

I'm trying to do something to the effect of:

```
if (firstChoice == A || B && secondChoice == A || B){
    //passes check.
}
```

Logically, I want this to pass if the first and second choice are either A or B. Is this syntax valid? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: So, to rephrase: if first is A or first is B OR if second is A or second is B.

Comment: What @JeroenVannevel said. Just change `is` to `==` and `and`/`or` to `&&`/`||` (also some parenthesis could be nice, even for readability).

Comment: You have to say something like `firstChoice == A || firstChoice == B`.  There isn't a shorthand for "some variable is value 1 or value 2 or value 3 or ...", at least not in the language itself; there might be a Google Guava method to accomplish something like this, but I'd have to look it up.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I think you need an "and" somewhere in there; I think he wants _both_ of his variables to meet the condition.

Comment: @ajb: probably have to switch the middle OR for an AND, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do `== A || B`; you can do this (but shouldn't, see below):

```
if ((firstChoice == A || firstChoice == B) &&
    (secondChoice == A || secondChoice == B)) {
```

That's about as readable as you're going to get it. Breaking it over a line makes it easier to follow the logic; horizontal scrolling is almost always a bad thing, and breaking it at the `&&` operator is the most readable way.

However, there's a way to make it more readable: create a helper method, which does what you want.

```
private boolean isAorB(YourObject choice) {
    return choice == A || choice == B;
}
```

Then your if statement would be:

```
if(isAorB(firstChoice) && isAorB(secondChoice)) {
```

This would be much more readable for future readers, including yourself, which is what you're really going for here.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (((firstChoice == A) || (firstChoice == B)) && ((secondChoice == A) || secondChoice == B)))
{
    //passes check.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((firstChoice == A || firstChoice == B) && (secondChoice == A || secondChoice == B)) {
    //do stuff
}
```

The thing to note here is that stuff like `(firstChoice == A || B)` makes sense when you read "firstChoice is equal to A or B" in your head but it doesn't make sense to Java. The left and right side of the || operator have to evaluate to a boolean. 'B' is not a boolean type (I'm assuming), but the condition `firstChoice == B` is.

Also, you can use parentheses to mark the order of operations, like you do with normal arithmetic. Even if they are not needed, it usually helps with readability.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment and others have mentioned, there's no shorthand for saying "if X equals A or B or C or..." or anything like that.  You have to say `if (x == a || x == b || x == c)`, etc.  (COBOL does allow that kind of expression, but unfortunately this useful feature hasn't found its way into the design of too many other languages.)

You can say:

```
if (isOneOf(firstChoice, A, B) || isOneOf(secondChoice, A, B)) {
    ...
}
```

if you define an `isOneOf` method like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> boolean isOneOf(T obj, T... choices) {
    for (T choice : choices) {
        if (choice.equals(obj)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Note that this allows for more than two choices.]